# Is there any R function to show earth map?

Tags: r, maps, r-highcharter

I have a problem with this code. The map appears but without color. I have installed tidiverse, highcharter, geonames,ggplot2, gganimate, maps, ggmap. Should I install some more packages?

```
population<-baza %>% 
  select(Country, Population)


highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df=population, value="Population", joinBy = "Country") %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(stops=color_stops()) %>% 
  hc_title(text="World Population") %>% 
  hc_tooltip(useHTML = TRUE,
             formatter = JS(
               "function(){",
               "  return '<b><u>'+this.point.Country+'</u></b><br>'",
               "         +'<b>Population:</b> '+parseInt(this.point.value);",
               "}"
             )
  ) %>% 
  hc_legend(
    enabled = TRUE,
    title = list(text = "Population"),
    layout = "vertical",
    align = "right",
    verticalAlign = "middle"
  )
```

Baza is my data frame with columns Country and Population.
Should something be added to this code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data, e.g. run `dput(head(population))` and add the output to your post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing do to with any missing packages, e.g. `highcharter` does not require `ggplot2`, `gganimate`, ... If a package is missing R will in general complain about that with an error message. And when you install a package using `install.packages` all needed dependency package will in general get installed too.

The most likely issue is that your dataset `population` can't be merged to the geojson data which might e.g. happen when you misspecified the `joinBy` column.

I had a look at the docs (`?hc_add_series_map`) and guessing that you use the `worldgeojson` data provided by `highcharter` the issue is that the `worldgeojson` data has no property `Country`, e.g. the country name is stored in a property `name`, the ISO3 country code in a property named `iso3`, ...

Hence, in that case a fix to your issue would be to rename your `Country` column.

Using some fake example `population` data where I assumed that `Country` contains the country name:

```r
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

population <- data.frame(
  Country = "United States of America",
  Population = 300
)

population <- population |> 
  rename(name = Country)

data(worldgeojson, package = "highcharter")

highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df = population, value = "Population", joinBy = "name") %>%
  hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops()) %>%
  hc_title(text = "World Population") %>%
  hc_tooltip(
    useHTML = TRUE,
    formatter = JS(
      "function(){",
      "  return '<b><u>'+this.point.Country+'</u></b><br>'",
      "         +'<b>Population:</b> '+parseInt(this.point.value);",
      "}"
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_legend(
    enabled = TRUE,
    title = list(text = "Population"),
    layout = "vertical",
    align = "right",
    verticalAlign = "middle"
  )
```

[image]